# association sequence rules mining with target label for very large data - which algorithm to use

Tags: r, sequence

1. I have a dataset in a list
2. each element of the list is a huge vector of symbols, more than 10k
3. vectors in a list of different lengths
4. there is a class label at the end of each vector
5. I needto find such sequences that will lead me to the class label here is a

> toy example data

```
set.seed(123)
win_seq <- c("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE") # for example this sequence occurs with the label "class_YES"
li <- list()
for(i in 1:4){
if(i<3){
v <- sample(letters,sample(30:50,1),replace = T)
v[ sort(sample(1:length(v),5))] <- win_seq   
v <- c(v,"class_YES")
li[[i]] <- v
}
if(i>=3){
    v <- sample(letters,sample(30:50,1),replace = T)
    v[  sample(1:length(v),5) ] <- win_seq 
    v <- c(v,"class_NO")
    li[[i]] <- v
  }
}
```

The first two  vectors of the list `li[[1]]` and `li[[2]]` have a sequence that can be associated with `class_YES`

```
"AA" > "BB" > "CC" > "DD" > "EE" > class_YES
```

[image]

The bottom line is that I need to find such sequences that are associated with labels  `class_YES` and `class_NO`

I found a package that can search associative sequence rules [arulesSequenses](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesSequences/arulesSequences.pdf)

But the problem is that the package looks for all the rules, all associations with all the elements, which makes it impossible to work with big data. But if you look for the rules only by the labels of interest, then you can reduce the search thousands of times

The question is, is there a package that can do the same as arulesSequences but

*1)that can work with big data

2)and in which you can set class labels*

Comment: Does your data have noise? I.e. Do all "YES" data contain the sequence and all "NO" data contain some other sequence?  Or, are you allowing for some randomness, such that "YES" data tend to contain the sub-sequence more likely than "NO" data (but not always)?

Comment: Hi! I think there is 99.9% noise in the data in both "yes" and "no", but I need to find at least something that distinguishes "yes" from "no" ..
The usual associative rules did not find anything because sequences are important